# Hydrate from array to objects with Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Given I have an array containing scalar values (that I trust), how would I convert them into doctrine entities?

eg:

```
array(
    array("name" => "Alex", "id" => 1)
    array("name" => "Chris", "id" => 2)
)
```

to an array of user entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know is do something like this:

```
// loop over the array
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // new entity
    $post = new User();

    // now loop over the properties of each post array...
    foreach ($user as $property => $value) {
        $method = sprintf('set%s', $property);
        // use the method as a variable variable to set your value
        $post->$method($value);
    }

    // persist the entity
    $em->persist($post);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the Serializer Component would be a clean approach:

```
$user = $serializer->deserialize(json_encode($data), 'Namespace\User', 'json');
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object

Comment: Can you explain that further? If `$data` contains a raw array, this throws an exception, as it tries to decode a JSON encoded string first

Comment: sorry, I forgot that you have to json_encode the array first. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this is a pretty old question, I'd like to add another way: Symfony ships a `PropertyAccessor` class which helps to determine getter and setter functions for a given object. `ucwords` is one of many ways to find them, and this accessor class tries to find all possibilities. Using that, the code of poxama could look like the following:

```php
$propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

// loop over the array
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // new entity
    $post = new User();

    // now loop over the properties of each post array...
    foreach ($user as $property => $value) {
        try {
            $propertyAccessor->setValue($user, $property, $value);
        } catch (NoSuchPropertyException $ex) {
            // go on
        }
    }

    // persist the entity
    $em->persist($post);
}
```